# Observable that cycles trough values

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have two Observables that are zipped. One generating a stream of events from an external source, and one generating a stream of predefined strings.

**Example code:**

```
import { interval, of, zip } from "rxjs";
import { pipe, mapTo } from "rxjs/operators";

let ticks$ = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo("Tick"));
let words$ = of("foo", "bar"); 

let ticker$ = zip(ticks$, words$);

ticker$.subscribe((e) => console.log(e));
```

This code works as expected, and outputs until `words$` runs out of elements, at which point it completes, and `ticker$` stops:

```
#=> ["Tick", "foo"]
#=> ["Tick", "bar"]
```

So far, so good. It works in accordance with the documentation for `#of`:

> An Observable that emits the arguments described above and then completes.

---

Now, I would like `words$` to be cycled. That is, when the last element has been emitted, it starts back at the beginning. So `ticker$`  will not stop:

```
#=> ["Tick", "foo"]
#=> ["Tick", "bar"]
#=> ["Tick", "foo"]
#=> ...
```

Looking at the documentation, there is no `#cycle` creator function.

How can I create an observable that cycles through a list of fixed values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this use `from` and combine with `repeat()`

```
let ticks$ = interval(10000).pipe(mapTo("Tick"));
let words$ = from(["foo", "bar"]).pipe(repeat());
```

Comment: I got this working after declaring `from` with `asyncScheduler`. :-)